# Functional dependencies and normal forms - database

Tags: database, functional-dependencies

Here I did 2 questions about functional relations and normal forms and i have some follow-up questions, things I couldn't find answers for.

```
1. On the relation scheme R(A, B, C, D, E, F) on which following 
functional dependencies are being applied:
F = {ABC →D, CE→B, E→C, BF→AC, E→F, F→E}. 
• Find (AB)+, (CD)+,(EF)+ 
• Find all candidate keys. 
• Find all function dependencies which cause this relation not to be at BCNF. 
(AB)+=AB | (CD)+=CD | (EF)+=EFCBAD

Find all candidate keys
(AB)+=AB     | (BF)+=BFECAD
(AC)+=AC     | (CE)+=CEBFAD
(AE)+=AECFBD | (CF)+=CFEBAD
(AF)+=AFECBD | (EF)+=EFCBAD
(BC)+=BC     | **(E)+=EFCBAD**
(BE)+=BECFAD | **(F)+=FECBAD**
Candidate keys are: E and F
Prime attributes are: E and F
Non-prime attributes are: A, B, C, D
Other Keys that functionally determines relation scheme R are not 
candidate keys because they don’t fulfill "minimality" rule!
```

2nd

```
2. On the relation scheme R = (A, B, C, D, E, F G, H) on which following 
functional dependencies are being applied:

F= {A →E, GH → C, DB → H, BG → A, C → D, G → H, H → B, AE → G} 
• Find (A)+ and (DBG)+ 
• Does G →B applies from fd F 
• Find all candidate keys. 
• In which normal form is following relations scheme? 
(AB)+=AB| (CD)+=CD | (EF)+=EFCBAD

Find all candidate keys:

**(A)+=AEGHBCD** | (B)+=B | (C)+=CD | (D)+=D | (E)+=E | (F)+=F | **(G)+=GHBCDAE** | 
(H)+=HB

Candidate keys are: A and G
Other Keys that functionally determines relation scheme R are not
candidate keys because they don’t fulfil minimality rule!
Prime elements are: A and G
Non prime elements are: B, C, D, E, H
1NF – yes
2NF – yes, because there are no partial key dependencies
3NF – no, because ABC ->D (functional dependency between 2 non-prime elements).
BCNF – no, because it is not in 3NF
```

QUESTIONS: 
1) Am I right with all of these that I wrote?

2) At 1st question, there are a lot of keys that are made by 2 elements, but they are not candidate keys, because the "minimal" rule is not applying on them. Am I right with this?

3) What if the part of the key is non-prime and part is prime element and that key functionally determines some other non-prime element. Is that relation at 3rd Normal form?

4) What if candidate part of the key (prime element) functionally determines another prime element, is that relation at 2nd Normal form?

5) In case there are a lot of keys that has "minimization" characteristics and they are candidate keys, do they all apply as candidate keys (for example 10 candidate keys)?

6) At 2nd question here, the F element is not being used in any functional dependency, but it is part of relation scheme. Do I left element F out, or element F must be part of the candidate key (also prime attribute/element)?

Comment: 1. Please explain what you are doing in "find all candidate keys". 2. Your 3) & 4) are unintelligible, please edit to be clear. 3. Please just post one question per question.

Comment: You have been given definitions & algorithms. Just follow them. Do not worry about any other property or thing you see. The definitions & algorithms already take everything into account. Eg re 5) By definition a CK is a (super)key that contains no smaller (super)key. Period. Does the definition talk about how many there are? No. Re 6) *What is the definition of CK*? *How were you told to find them*? Just apply what you were told.